# Use of nozzle as a refrigeration device

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hvac, refrigeration

When compressed air passes through a nozzle, its velocity increases while its temperature decreases due to the pressure drop. Why is this process not utilized as a refrigeration system similar to air conditioner? Could the high exit velocity at the nozzle exit be a potential barrier to this application?

Comment: like this: https://intersam.es/en/what-is-an-adiabatic-cooling-system-and-its-advantages/

Comment: Refrigeration devices *do* use expansion of compressed *refrigerants* to cool things. They use use refrigerants that are more efficient than air.

Comment: Google `vortex cooling tube`

Comment: That's pretty much exactly how refrigerators work, except they use an orifice or needle valve instead of a nozzle, and refrigerant fluid which has much better thermal properties for this purpose than air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pressurization of air (or other gas I suppose) were free this might be viable.  We also need to dump the heat we make compressing the air. Certainly we could make a nozzle that had whatever pressure drop required.  We might struggle figuring out how to get heat into that moving air, it isn't the best way to transfer heat. But air definitely cools when it expands, so the possibility is there.

The advantage of the standard refrigeration cycle is that it moves more heat than the energy used.  You could never get that multiplier effect with direct expansion.

Comment: I think it can be used for spot cooling of electronic equipments, but the pressure should be low otherwise the exit velocity will be high which might damage the equipment

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it could cause the line to freeze up. A refrigerator is a lot different from an air conditioning unit, even using a system like this, you still have to cover your line/tube installation covering to prevent your lines from freezing up. Plus the design may not work as well with a refrigerator and may work best for an air condition unit. Although this idea may have already been thought of before. Good Question though.